# Is it possible for my application to minimize a task running in the background like the in-call minimzed system tray in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, system-tray, minimized

I'm not really sure if it is a control or something which is exclusive to VoIP / Call Applications but I would like to be able to run a task in the background and display the progress minimized to the system tray just like an active call minimizes itself in Phone / Viber or other Voip apps.

Please see the below picture:

[image]

Instead of "Active call duration and contact name", could I possibly use it to show progress for ex - `"Downloading XX%..."` and then the user could tap to return back to the application?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Voip Apps have a special access to the call UI overlay, as documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206983(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for by somehow implementing the VoIP-exclusive UI Overlay?

Comment: I have also seen the Overlay in Bluetooth File Transfer. Is there no way it can be implemented by third party devs?

Comment: You can only use it for VoiP calls and will not get it to open without an actual call in the background. Also, you probably won't get certified in the store. Bluetooths overlay also is just a system overlay you will not be able to access.

Comment: If there was a workaround, I think a lot of apps would already be doing that and it would probably be very annoying.